Existence of smooth integers in every residue class with large modulus
Let us say that a positive integer $x$ is $y$-power smooth, if the largest prime power divisor of $x$ is at most $y$. In what follows, let $C$ be any real number larger than $1$ and, for an integer $x$, define the interval $I_x = [x, Cx]$. I have been trying to find in the literature a result that would imply the following:
There is a positive constant $c > 0$ and a positive integer $x_0$ such that for all $x \ge x_0$ there are at least $cx$ integers $m \in I_x$ such that for every integer $a$ coprime to $m$, there exists a $x^{0.2}$-power smooth integer $n \in (x, x^{1.9})$ with $n \equiv a \pmod{m}$.
I expect all integers $m \in I_x$ to have this property (if $x$ is large enough), but this is presumably hard to prove. I therefore settle for a positive density of such $m$. Can anyone point me to a reference where this is proven?
